# How to uninstall the latest update for Visual studio 2017?

Tags: updates, visual-studio-2017, microsoft.codeanalysis

After updating to the 21st of June update for Visual studio 2017, I'm no longer able to build my project.

I'm getting a BadImageException, the signature is incorrect on Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.

I've tried to clean solution, reboot computer, repair visual studio 2017 (and resharper) (in that order).

I can build in release but I can not build in debug. Obviously, this is a problem for me.

How can I undo the latest visual studio 2017 update? In visual studio 2015 you used to be able to simply undo the updates but in visual studio 2017 this seems to be obscured.

Comment: Does the update show up in the classic control panel > "programs and features" > "installed updates"?

Comment: @zett42 Only for previous versions of visual studios but not for 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a dead question but I resolved this by simply uninstalling the entire installation and reinstalling it (including the update) and that resolved it for me.

Comment: not so dead. I just installed latest update and xamarin forms doesn't deploy to android device anymore. Installed Update: VS Community 2019 version 16.7.7

Comment: Reinstall of VS helped out.

Comment: Same thing happened to me with VS 2019 16.11.6.  It no longer single-steps in source code mode into some functions, but goes into disassembly, showing also the source code.  It also has lags when navigating and editing source file.  Would be nice to be able to roll back to the prior version.